# Area 51 - All Proposals Display Bug

Tags: bug, area-51

I was on Area 51 and I noticed a bad display bug for the [All Proposals tab](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). The tab label is supposed to say "All Proposals x proposals". It does say this, but the "x proposals" doesn't fit in the box.

Here's a picture

[image: bad area 51 display]

This happens on Chrome and Firefox on an Ubuntu system and Chrome on a mobile device. No console errors either. And I swear I'm not playing with Dev Tools.

Comment: I can't reproduce on Safari 7 (Mac). What browser you are using?

Comment: Your font looks different. I can't repro on Google Chrome,  IE or FF on win7

Comment: @rene I'm on Chrome

Comment: Try it in incognito mode with all extensions disabled

Comment: No repro as well, latest Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: @rene That doesn't work either

Comment: Are you at 100% zoom? But: no repo, (like others mentioned) your font is different.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin Yes, but it doesn't change even when I zoom in and out

Comment: Any errors in the Dev console? Different browser?

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin No console errors. Same thing happens in Firefox

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the font installed on your system?

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin Maybe, but this happens on my mobile device too

Comment: Ummm... maybe your ISP is infested by phpBB admins?!?!?!

Comment: I can only repro this if I leave `sans-serif` on the css style `font-family: Impact, "Futura-CondensedExtraBold", sans-serif` which basically means that your browser either refuses to use the Impact or "Futura-CondensedExtraBold" or they are no longer present on that system

Comment: No repro on Ubuntu 14.04 Chrome

Comment: I see exactly what you do in both Safari and Chrome on my iPad 2, version 8.1.1.  In fact, I never knew there was supposed to be anything else in that box! I tried scrolling and nothing happened.